# Jquery validate addMethod validate for custom method

Tags: jquery, regex, jquery-validate

Im using jquery validate and I wish to add a method that input text cannot contain **".com"**

Im tried:

```
    //.com Validator
    $.validator.addMethod('dotcom', function(value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || (!value.match(/[.com]/) && value.match(/[.com]/));
    },
    dotcom);
```

But this doesn't work, any suggestion to do that ? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your regex test is wrong. Try

```js
var dotcom = 'Value cannot contain `.com`'
$.validator.addMethod('dotcom', function(value, element) {
  return this.optional(element) || !/\.com/.test(value);
}, dotcom);


$('form').validate({
  rules: {
    site: {
      dotcom: true
    }
  }
})

$('button').click(function() {
  $('form').valid();
  return false;
})
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.12.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.12.0/additional-methods.js"></script>

<form>
  <div>
    <input name="site" />
  </div>
  <button>Save</button>
</form>
```

Comment: if I want input must have "com." so how ? I tried `/\com./.test(value);` but doesn't work

Comment: @TheSmile try `return this.optional(element) || /\.com/.test(value);`

Comment: but if I want "com." not ".com"

Comment: @TheSmile then `return this.optional(element) || /com/.test(value);`

Comment: cannot include **"."** ?

Comment: I tried include but when type com it already consider correct

Comment: @TheSmile sorry `return this.optional(element) || /com\./.test(value);`